# Identify email message related to received webhook

Tags: email, sendgrid, webhooks

Today I started to learn about webhooks and I was wondering if it is possible to know exactly what message is related to a received webhook.

For example, I have a website where customers can register and, after a successful registration, I'm sending them a confirmation via email. Is it possible to know that the customer clicked on that specific email message? (Considering that the customer can receive other types of email messages like password recovery, newsletters, etc). I know I can use the subject (something like if subject == 'Welcome to My Site' then do-email-post-registration-clicked-routine) but if the subject changes, or if they change it (when we reply to a message, usually the email client prepends "Re:" to the subject, I won't be able to track it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use custom arguments to track individual emails. Custom arguments get sent with event webhooks.

More documentation can be found here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html